# Derivation of luminosity source counts

Tags: chain-rule

For my cosmology assignment, we're required to derive an expression for the source count $\frac{dN}{dS}$ and show that it is $$ \cfrac{dN}{dS} ∝ \cfrac{S^{-3}}{\cos \theta}$$

We start from a Universe that resides on the surface of a sphere and we consider a spherical and an observer at the pole. I was able to show that the volume enclosed using polar coordinates was $$V=2\pi R^2(1-\cos \theta)$$, and that the flux for the observer is $$ S= \cfrac{L}{2 \pi R \sin \theta}$$

Where I am confused is that we are asked to find an expression for $$ \cfrac{dV}{d \theta}$$  and $$\cfrac{dN}{d\theta} $$ and I am not too sure how to go on about this as all substitutions I have made like $$\sin \theta ∝ s^{-1}$$ do not seem to lead to the expected result.

I came up with $$dN = \text{density} \times \text{surface area}\, d\theta$$

and

$$dV ∝ \cos \theta d \theta$$

since we are talking about a 2d universe.

A slight nudge in the right direction will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to math SE. Have a look at [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for your mathematical expressions.

Comment: Thank you! It is a lot better.